# Exception : Could not initialize class HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an exception when I try to connect a user. This exception is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class fr.inra.grignon.persyst.common.util.HibernateUtil
    fr.inra.grignon.persyst.web.servlet.DoLogin.doPost(DoLogin.java:32)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I saw on some posts that it was an error with hibernate 4 and the way we create the session factory. But I am using hibernate **3.3.1**. 
In the HibernateUtil.java, I have :

```
package fr.inra.grignon.persyst.common.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
   public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   static {
      try {
         // Création de la SessionFactory à partir de hibernate.cfg.xml
         sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      } catch (Throwable ex) {
         // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
         System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
      }
   }

   public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      return sessionFactory;
   }
}
```

On the creation of the sessionFactory (`public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory`), I have a warning :
**Constant name does not follow naming conventions: sessionFactory**

Comment: What is the actual exception that gets thrown? Try replacing `System.err.println` with `ex.printStackTrace()` and post the output

Comment: @PredragMaric I tried but ex.printStackTrace() doesn't work :/

Comment: @PredragMaric With it, the exception is "org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started